# CakePHP 3.0 saving belongsToMany not saving

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, model, cakephp-3.0

I am having trouble saving associated data in Cake 3.0. I have a Users Model, and a user can be many different musicians. I have a join table users_musicians.

```
class UsersTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsToMany('Musicians', [
            'joinTable' => 'users_musicians',
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('Counties', [
            'foreignKey' => 'county_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }
```

I am posting over a new user, and trying to save a single musician type in the users_musicians table, using the musician_id posted over and using the user_id of the new user saved.

```
public function add() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        $newData = [
            'users_musicians' => [
                ['musician_id' => 10],
            ]
        ];
        $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $newData);

        echo '<br><br><pre>' . print_r($user, true) . '</pre>';
        //die();
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your details have been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your details.'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

Table structue of "users_musicians" is: 
id - int, AI, PK,
user_id - int,
musician_id - int,
created - datetime,
updated - datetime

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, associating a new `Users` record with an already existing `Musicians` record that has a primary key of `10`?

Comment: I was just adding something in to see if it would save. I actually got it working after I created a new MusiciansUsers model with belongsTo relationship between it an Users. So it now saves to the musucians_users table as I wanted. I renamed this table after advice from aavrug below.

Answer (score 2):

In CakePHP for belongsToMany association the table name should be in alphabetical order so, change the "users_musicians" table name to "musicians_users" and try it.

Comment: this was case to me `ValidationsCountryGroups` table was giving an error, but `CountryGroupsValidations` works fine